# How to fix OpenLayers 6 errors after upgrade

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

After upgrading to OpenLayers 6.6.1 I'm receiving the error

> Generic type 'VectorLayer' requires 1 type argument(s)
>
> Generic type 'Feature' requires 1 type argument(s).

On this code...

```
 import olLayerVector from 'ol/layer/Vector';
 import olFeature from 'ol/Feature';

 public static highlightOverlay: olLayerVector = new olLayerVector({});
 const selectedFeatures: Array<olFeature> = 
 MapValues.highlightOverlay.getSource().getFeatures();
```

I've looked through https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases and I cannot find reference to this being changed or what it should be changed to?

I have 77 errors to fix and no guide as to how to upgrade?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Who throws these errors? I suppose this is typescript? Have you tried this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/openlayers

Comment: So I found this thread from 2019
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8673
essentially it says use // @ts-ignore on typescript errors in OpenLayers...this is not a good solution when typescript is showing 100+ errors...

Comment: yes this was 2019. Maybe the release notes for the Version 6.6.0 help: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/ 
  ol now has it's own types, you might need to update your `tsconfig.json`